# How do i provide a Console-Hosted WCF Service on localhost to the outside via my domain?

Tags: c#, wcf, localhost

I have got the following problem:

I host a WCF Service in a Console Application on a Server at localhost:72/service .

This Port is reachable from the outside via e.g. mydomain.org:62345/service .

If I try now to retrieve and add the service reference to this service from a (external) desktop application, i get a 400:bad request, because the app tries to retrieve the wsdl from localhost:72/service?wsdl instead of mydomain.org:62345/service?wsdl.

How can i change my Console Application in order for this to work right?

THX in advance, Martin

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MSSQL_MasterToDesktop_Service.Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:72/Service")))
        {

            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MSSQL_MasterToDesktop_Service.ISync), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
           //sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MSSQL_MasterToDesktop_Service.ISync), new WSHttpBinding(), 

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);


            sh.Open();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections...");
            System.Console.ReadLine();


            sh.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't host the service at `localhost`, but instead use the IP of the system's LAN card, or use "0.0.0.0" for all network interfaces ('*' or '+' might do as well).

In order for the service to be reachable from outside your LAN you may need to setup some port forwarding in your router.